# Three.js light position visibly changes but position attribute stays the same

Tags: three.js

I have a light that is a child to a pivot object:

```
var pivotpoint = new THREE.Object3D();
pivotpoint.name="pivot";
scene.add(pivotpoint);

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
light.name = "light";
light.castShadow = true;
pivotpoint.add( light );
light.position.set(10,25,0);
```

Now, in my update() method I rotate the pivot object:

```
var o = scene.getObjectByName("pivot");
if(GLOBAL_KEYS['a'])
{
    o.rotation.y += 0.05;
}
if(GLOBAL_KEYS['d'])
{
    o.rotation.y -= 0.05;
}
```

This works perfectly well. I can see my light rotating around the pivot point, casting shadows and all.

However, if I do...

```
console.log(light.position);
```

...the position attribute always stays at (10,25,0).
What in god's name do I need to do in order to get the **actual** light position??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object.position` is a local position, relative to the object's parent in the scene graph. To compute position in global space, use `getWorldPosition`:

```js
const worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
light.getWorldPosition(worldPos);
console.log(worldPos);
```